# Formatting Python Requests according to the following headers

Tags: python, rest, file-upload, python-requests, advanced-rest-client

I am trying to use Python Requests library to POST a zipped file as multipart/form-data. I have currently used the Chrome Extension Advanced REST Client that is able to upload the file without a problem. However, I face difficulties while trying to do the same from the console using Python Requests.

The general information for the request is:

```
Remote Address:IP/Address/to/Host:Port
Request URL:/path/to/host/with/parameters/
Request Method:POST
```

The request headers from Advanced REST Client are:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:Basic/Authentication
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1893
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryu3rhOVbU2LpT89zi
Host:/host/name
Origin:chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
```

The payload is as follows:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryu3rhOVbU2LpT89zi
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="filename.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


------WebKitFormBoundaryu3rhOVbU2LpT89zi--
```

I formatted this query in Python as follows:

```
import requests

authentication = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(username=user, password=pass)
parameters = {} # with the appropriate parameters
url = '' # base URL
files = {'file': ('fileUpload', 'application/x-zip-compressed', {})}

response = requests.post(url, params = parameters, auth=authentication, files=files)
```

While the Chrome App, Advanced REST Client gives me a `200 OK` response, I get a `400` response (bad query). What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!